# Sanitizing Thunderbird 3.0

Tags: thunderbird

The new Mozilla Thunderbird has a new folder layout for multiple accounts. The common folders such as Inbox, Trash and Draft are placed in the root, while custom folders are placed under the respective accounts.

I can't imagine what the folks at Mozilla have been thinking, as I find this very inconvenient. Is there any way to revert to the sensible old layout where all folders are sorted under the respective account root folder?

Also, the new automated e-mail account configuration wizard is a pain and never seem to get anything right. Can it somehow be disabled? I'd rather just go to the full configuration tab than having to battle with a broken wizard with a mind of it's own.

Comment: i went straight back to TB 2.x, version 3 is an outright pain in the behind, and the claim that 3 is faster than 2 is plain false.

Comment: I'd have to disagree - TB3 works well for me on Windows (Mac OSX is a different story, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off the new world folder view by changing the setting in View -> Folders from Smart to All. At least that did the trick for me.

I just noticed (on a freshly installed TB3) that there is another way also. The 'Smart Folders' designation has a left and right arrow next to it. You can use them to switch between the Smart Folders view and the regular one.

Comment: Ah, there we go. I knew they must have hidden it somewhere I'd never think to look :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Migration Assistant in the Help menu. It has explanations for the new behaviour of a few of the major new features/changes and the ability to revert to the old behaviours.